# ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types

Tags: database, error-handling, sas

Good day

Been trying to look for answers all over the internet, but had to ask the question, as it doesn't seem to be a standard data type issue.

I get the error:
ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types.

This is the script:

```
Create Table Work.Gross_Premiums_&Report_Date as
Select Distinct  AIC.POLICY_NUMBER,
                 IFC(AIC.SOURCE_DATA in ('ID','PL','FSP'),(Substr(AIC.FORMATTED_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,3,13)||"*"||Substr(AIC.FORMATTED_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,14,3)),FORMATTED_ACCOUNT_NUMBER) as FORMATTED_POLICY_NUMBER,
                 AIC.SOURCE_DATA,
                 SUM(ID.Prem) AS ID_GROSS_PREMIUM,
                 SUM(AFS.GROSS_PREMIUM) AS AFS_GROSS_PREMIUM,
                 SUM(PL.PremInclVat) as PL_GROSS_PREMIUM,
                 SUM(FSP.Premium_charged) as FSP_GROSS_PREMIUM,
                 SUM(IJ.GROSS_PREMIUM) AS IJ_GROSS_PREMIUM,
                 SUM(SUM(ID.Prem),SUM(AFS.GROSS_PREMIUM),SUM(PL.PremInclVat),SUM(FSP.Premium_charged),SUM(IJ.GROSS_PREMIUM)) as WIMI_INCOME

                 From WORK.AIC_&Report_Date AIC
                 Left Join IDIRECT.TRNWRITTEN ID On (AIC.POLICY_NUMBER = (ID.ClientID || ID.FileNo))
                 Left Join WORK.AFS_&Report_Date AFS On (AIC.FORMATTED_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = AFS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) 
                 Left Join PL.TRNWRITTENPREM PL On (AIC.POLICY_NUMBER = Put(PL.ClientID,z8.)||Put(PL.FileNo,z3.))
                 Left Join FSP.POLICY_TRANSACTIONS FSP On (AIC.FORMATTED_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = Put(FSP.POLICY_NUMBER,z16.) )
                 Left Join WORK.INSUREJ IJ on (AIC.POLICY_NUMBER = IJ.POLICY_NUMBER)

                 Where (AIC.SOURCE_DATA = 'FSP' 
                        and InPut(Put(Input('Transaction date'n,ANYDTDTM19.),DATETIME21.2),Date9.) Between INTNX('MONTH',"&Report_Date."d,0,'BEGIN') 
                        and "&Report_Date."d and 'Paid / unpaid'n = 1) 
                         OR AIC.SOURCE_DATA <> 'FSP'
                 Group By AIC.POLICY_NUMBER, AIC.SOURCE_DATA, (CALCULATED FORMATTED_POLICY_NUMBER);
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help identify the issue.

Best regards,
Eugene

Comment: I'd recommend that you simplify your query until you have the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the error and then update your question.  90% of that code probably isn't relevant to the issue, and I doubt many people feel like digging through it.  Doing this will probably help you to solve your own problem as well =)

Answer (score 0):

This means you are comparing numeric and character values.  The most likely culprits are `(AIC.POLICY_NUMBER = IJ.POLICY_NUMBER)` or `(AIC.POLICY_NUMBER = (ID.ClientID || ID.FileNo))`.

In the first example, check both policy_number variables to ensure they are the same data type.
For the second example, if `AIC.POLICY_NUMBER` is numeric then you will get the error message as you are comparing to a character value

Answer (score 0):

You also have an issue with this section of your code:

```
InPut(Put(Input('Transaction date'n,ANYDTDTM19.),DATETIME21.2),Date9.)
```

I would expect to see `DATEPART()` or `DTDATE9.` used to convert the variable into a datetime. Without knowing exactly how it looks like ahead of time, this is a bit of a guess, but I think its your issue:

```
datepart(input('Transaction date'n, ANYDTDTM19.)) between  ...
```